# Group by select based on OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

After using UNION with two select queries, I'm getting following results

```
UserId    Name    Status
------   ------  --------
1   User1   Active
2   User2   Active
1   User1   InActive
3   User3   InActive
```

But the expected results is

```
UserId Name Status
---------------------
1   User1   Active
2   User2   Active
3   User3   InActive
```

Here what I need is, I want to group by column Id and get status as Active if any one result is active. How to form a SQL query for this?

Can anyone suggest query for any one of the following DB?

1. MSSQL
2. Oracle
3. MySQL
4. PostgreSQL

**Edit:**

This is the query I've tried in PostgreSQL

```
(SELECT DISTINCT User.Id,User.DisplayName,AppAccessToUsers.IsActive='1' AND User.IsActive='1' AS IsStatusActive 
FROM Applications Left JOIN AppAccessToUsers ON (Applications.Id=AppAccessToUsers.ApplicationId) 
Left JOIN User ON (AppAccessToUsers.UserId=User.Id) WHERE Applications.ClientId='e7e66c1b-b3b8-4ffb-844b-fc4840803265') 
UNION 
(SELECT DISTINCT User.Id,User.DisplayName,AppAccessToGroups.IsActive='1' AND Group.IsActive='1' AND UserGroup.IsActive='1' AND User.IsActive='1' AS IsStatusActive 
FROM Applications Left JOIN AppAccessToGroups ON (Applications.Id=AppAccessToGroups.ApplicationId) 
Left JOIN Group ON (AppAccessToGroups.GroupId=Group.Id) Left JOIN UserGroup ON (Group.Id=UserGroup.GroupId) 
Left JOIN User ON (UserGroup.UserId=User.Id) WHERE Applications.ClientId='e7e66c1b-b3b8-4ffb-844b-fc4840803265')
```

Comment: what query you have tried

Comment: And based on what do you decide if a user has both active and inactive record, then which one should prevail?

Comment: Any of them? Will you chose db depending on the answer you get here?

Comment: @Shadow I want to get status as active if user has atleaset one active record

Comment: @jarlh I'm using all the the DB listed above. It can be helpful you can suggest for anyone Database

Answer (score 1):

Use this query,

```
SELECT  UserId
        ,Name
        ,CASE WHEN min(status) = 'Active' THEN 'Active' ELSE 'InActive' END
FROM users GROUP BY UserId,Name
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following, assuming a) your tables are called t1 and t2 (amend as appropriate for your actual table names) and b) the names for each userid in both tables are the same - ie. for userid = 1, both tables have the same name:

```
SELECT userid,
       NAME,
       MIN(status)
FROM   (SELECT userid, NAME, status FROM t1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT userid, NAME, status FROM t2)
GROUP BY userid, NAME;
```

This works in Oracle, and I'm pretty sure it'll work in the other database platforms you mentioned.

N.B. I used `MIN(status)` since you appear to want a status of Active to override a status of Inactive, and A comes before I in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

for postgres you can use `CASE` and `bool_or`, eg:

```
t=# with a(i,n,b) as (
  values (1,'a','active'), (1,'a','inactive'), (2,'b','inactive'), (2,'b','inactive')
)
select i,n,case when bool_or(b = 'active') then 'active' else 'inactive' end
from a
group by i,n
;
 i | n |   case
---+---+----------
 1 | a | active
 2 | b | inactive
(2 rows)
```

Comment: `bool_or(b='active')`

Answer (score 0):

In Sql-server, you could use `group by` or `Row_number` like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
   UserId    int,
   Name   varchar(20),
   Status varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
   UserId,Name,Status
)
VALUES
(1,'User1', 'Active'),
(2,'User2', 'Active'),
(1,'User1', 'InActive'),
(3,'User3', 'InActive')

-- use row_number
;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.UserId ORDER BY sd.Status ) AS Rn
   FROM @SampleData sd
)
SELECT t.UserId, t.Name, t.Status
FROM temp t WHERE t.Rn = 1

--or use group by
SELECT sd.UserId, sd.Name, min(sd.Status) AS status 
FROM @SampleData sd
GROUP BY sd.UserId, sd.Name
```

Results:

```
UserId  Name    Status
1      User1    Active
2      User2    Active
3      User3    InActive
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of MS Sql Server you can try row_number

```
;with cte as (
select top 1 with ties * from
( select * from #youruser
    union all
  select * from #youruser) a
order by row_number() over (partition by userid order by [status] desc) 
) select * from cte where status = 'Active'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select your_table.* from your_table
inner join (
    select UserId, min(Status) as st from your_table
    group by UserId
) t
on your_table.UserId = t.UserId and your_table.Status = t.st
```

Note: if same `UserId` can have same `Status` more than 1 times, then this returns duplicated results.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte (UserId, Name,Status)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'User1','Active'   Union all
SELECT 2,'User2','Active'   Union all
SELECT 1,'User1','InActive' Union all
SELECT 3,'User3','InActive'
)
SELECT UserId
    ,NAME
    ,[Status]
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY UserId
            ,NAME ORDER BY STATUS
            ) AS Seq
    FROM cte
    ) dt
WHERE dt.Seq = 1
```

OutPut

```
UserId  Name    Status
-----------------------
1       User1   Active
2       User2   Active
3       User3   InActive
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
Note : Group by is to remove duplicate

select 
A.USERID, A.NAME,A.STATUS
from TAB_1 A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM TAB_1 WHERE STATUS='Active') B
ON A.USERID=B.USERID
WHERE
( B.STATUS IS NULL OR A.STATUS=B.STATUS)
GROUP BY A.USERID, A.NAME,A.STATUS
ORDER BY A.USERID
;
```